# How can I count array's items condetionally?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$arr [
         ["name" = "Martin", "type" = "0"],
         ["name" = "Jack", "type" = "0"],
         ["name" = "Tiam", "type" = "1"]
     ];
```

Now I need to count the number of items that have `type=0`. Currently I use `count($arr)` which returns `3`. And the expected result is `2`.

---

I can do that using a loop plus an if-statement inside. But isn't there any better idea?

Comment: code golf time: one liner `echo array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'type'))[0];`

Comment: Challenge accepted: `foreach($arr as$a)$a['type']||$c++;echo$c;`

Comment: Ghost and Progrock your codes seem professional. good for you guys.,

Comment: @Ghost Just your code has a problem. It will throw a warning if the array is empty.

Comment: @MartinAJ just add a ternary condition with empty, easy peasy, by the way, don't forget to accept an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = array_filter($arr,function($item){
    return $item['type'] == 0;
});

echo count($result);
```

[Array Filter Docs](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-filter.php)

[Functional Programming in PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html)

Comment: I think it would be better to use: return $item['type'] === "0";

Comment: Yes, it would. But it seems that he has strings for the 'type' key.

Comment: Yes, if it's strict comparison you want then @NoOorZ24's suggestion is fine.

Answer (score 2):

array_filter should do the trick:

```
$arr = [
["name" => "Martin", "type" => "0"],
["name" => "Jack", "type" => "0"],
["name" => "Tiam", "type" => "1"]
];

$arr = array_filter($arr,function($item){
    return $item['type']==0;
});

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        $arr  = array(
            array(
            'name' => 'Martin',
            'type' => '0',
        ),
            array(
            'name' => 'Martin',
            'type' => '0',
        ),
            array(
            'name' => 'Martin',
            'type' => '25',
        )
        );

        $arr = array_filter($arr,function($item){
    return $item['type']==0;
});

echo count($arr);
        die;
```